# How to define the return type of React FunctionalComponent in TypeScript definition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

I'm getting the following error on running `tsc --strict`:

```
Function implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.
```

Maybe I'm defining the type wrong, but I can't find anywhere how to do this properly. I've looked at the `React.FC` type and my understanding is that it's an alias of `React.FunctionComponent` which makes it inherit a return value of `ReactElement`. So In my understanding this should work or at least not be an `implicit any`. Below my type definition and the component.

I'm using the JSdoc notation for checking my JS files with the typescript definitions. Notation is like this:

```
/**
 * LoadingIndicator - Just a simple loading spinner..
 *
 * @type LoadingIndicator { import("../../types/index.d.ts").LoadingIndicator }
 */
```

My exported type in `index.d.ts`:

```
export const LoadingIndicator: React.FC<LoadingIndicatorProps>;
```

My functional component:

```
const LoadingIndicator = ({ size = 15, color = '#006CFF' }) => (
    <div
      className={'loading-indicator ' + color}
      style={{ width: size, height: size }}
    >
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try in this way

```
const LoadingIndicator: React.FC<LoadingIndicatorProps> = ({ size = 15, color = '#006CFF' }) => (
  <div
    className={'loading-indicator ' + color}
    style={{ width: size, height: size }}
  >
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Problem is I'm not using .ts files but I'm checking my JS files with the JSdoc notation. Updated my question to reflect this.